# How to fix: Some required packages could not be installed. Check internet connection

Tags: android

I'm running on Ubuntu 16, with Java 8.
I just downloaded Android Studio 2.1.
When Running Android Studio and trying to create a new project, I'm getting the following error:
"Some required packages could not be installed. Check internet connection"

What is the problem and how can I fix it ?
It is really so hard to create a simple "hello world" android application ?

Answer (score 0):

May be the android components are not installed properly...go to SDK Manager and download all the necessary packages..